# Prove that in a quadrilateral, the lines joining the midpoints of the opposite sides and the midpoints of the diagonals are concurrent

Tags: geometry

Prove that in a quadrilateral, the lines joining the midpoints of the opposite sides and the midpoints of the diagonals are concurrent.

We construct an arbitrary quadrilateral $ABCD$ with $E, F, G$ as the midpoints of $AB, BC, CD$. Let $H, I$ be the midpoints of $AC, BD$. Let $EG, HI$ intersect at $J$. Let the line joining $F, J$ meet $AD$ at $K$. We will prove that $K$ is the midpoint of $DA$.

[image]

Joining $KG, GF, FE, EK$, it quickly becomes clear that the above is only true if $KGFE$ is a parallelogram, which in turn, is only true if $EJ = JG, KJ = JF$. Proving the first equality is easy.

In $\Delta ABC, EH || BC, 2\cdot EH = BC$. Likewise, in $\Delta DBC, IG || BC, 2\cdot IG = BC$. Therefore, $IG||EH, IG=EH$. Therefore, $EHGI$ is a parallelogram and $EJ = JG$. Even after numerous efforts I wasn't able to prove the second equality.

I noticed that this was because I was not utilizing the fact that $F$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and that $FK$ is the straight line.

So, to utilize those facts, I considered $\Delta HKJ, \Delta JFI$. Proving these are congruent will prove our conjecture. Now, we can use the fact that $FK$ is a straight line by saying, that $\angle HJK = \angle IJF$. Also, since $EHGI$ is a parallelogram, $HJ = JI$. Now we need only one more equivalence to prove congruency. I wasn't able to find this.

A way to utilize the fact that $F$ is the midpoint of $BC$ is by noticing that $EHCF, IGFC, AHFE, FIDG$ are all parallelograms. I have, however, no idea how to use these in the proof.

I think I'm forgetting something. Because in each approach I take, there is always a single piece that is missing. If anybody could point out what this 'piece' is, I would be grateful. I would appreciate solutions that are related to the approaches described above.

Comment: The result certainly *seems* true when you squint your eyes and imagine that $ABCD$ is in fact a tetrahedron. If you already knew that lines joining midpoints of opposite edges of a tetrahedron concur, you'd be done ... but I don't think this is a well-known fact (although it's about as easy to show as the fact that the midpoint polygon of a quadrilateral is a parallelogram).

Comment: Don't you want to use vector? Using vector is better, I think.

Comment: The apparent parallelograms ($KGFE$, $KHFI$, $HEIG$) are *actual* parallelograms, because they're the midpoint polygons of various quadrilaterals (which may be "bow-tie" quads, but that's okay).

Comment: If will probably easier if you set $K$ as the midpoint of $AD$ and show all three lines
$EG$, $FK$ and $HI$ intersect at the same point $J$.

When $K$ is the mid-point of $AD$, $EFGH$ is a parallelogram. So $EG$ and $FK$ intersect
at a point $J$ which is the midpoint of $EG$ and $FK$. Similarly, $FIKH$ is another parallelogram, so $FK$ and $HI$ intersect at another point $J'$ which is the midpoint of $FK$ and $HI$. Since both $J$ and $J'$ are midpoint of $FK$, $J = J'$ and we are done.

Comment: @mathlove: Yes, if you know a solution using vectors, post it. I always prefer Euclidean geometry, but a different outlook on the problem is always helpful.

Comment: @achillehui: Nice solution! I didn't approach the problem that way because it seemed complicated. Proving that $K$ was the midpoint of $DA$ was a much more 'familiar' result to prove rather than proving that two points coincided.

Comment: @Gerard, it is usually more complicated. But in this case, if you think in terms of vector like others suggested, then it is sort of obvious $\vec{J} = \frac14 \left(\vec{A}+\vec{B}+\vec{C}+\vec{D}\right)$, so you know the complicated way will give you an answer. You just look for geometric constructs to help you translate a vector based proof to a pure geometric proof. Guessing the right answer usually solves half of the problem.

Comment: @achillehui: Yes, using the vectors it can be easily seen that $J$ is the required point of concurrency. But I don't see how you concluded from this that the complicated way will give us an answer.

Comment: @Gerard, Given $\vec{A}, \vec{B}, \vec{C},\vec{D}$, there are 3 ways to generate $\vec{J}$ algberically and hence geometrically using midpoints:

$$\begin{align}\vec{J} 
&= \frac12 \left[\frac12\left(\vec{A}+\vec{B}\right) + \frac12\left(\vec{C}+\vec{D}\right)\right] = \frac12\left(\vec{E}+\vec{G}\right)\\
&= \frac12 \left[\frac12\left(\vec{A}+\vec{D}\right) + \frac12\left(\vec{B}+\vec{C}\right)\right] = \frac12\left(\vec{K}+\vec{F}\right)\\
&= \frac12 \left[\frac12\left(\vec{A}+\vec{C}\right) + \frac12\left(\vec{B}+\vec{D}\right)\right] = \frac12\left(\vec{H}+\vec{I}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: The reason polygons like $EFGH$ is a parallelogram because edges like $\vec{EF}$, $\vec{HG}$ are both equal to $\frac12 \vec{AC}$ and the midpoints of $EG$ and $FH$ coincides
because they are different ways of computing $\vec{J}$. All the construct looks complicated geometrically but they have very simple algebraic correspondence.

Comment: we can say that the barycenter of unit masses at the four vertices is also a) the barycenter of the barycenters of the diagonals b) the barycenter of the barycenters of the sides

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to write an answer using vectors.

Let $O$ be the intersection point of $AC, BD$.

Let $$\vec{OA}=\vec{a}, \vec{OB}=\vec{b}, \vec{OC}=k\vec{a}, \vec{OD}=l\vec{b}$$
where $k,l\lt 0.$

Letting $E,F,G,H$ be the midpoints of $AB, BC, CD, DA$ respectively, we have
$$\vec{OE}=\frac{1}{2}\vec a+\frac 12\vec b,\vec{OF}=\frac 12\vec b+\frac k2\vec a, \vec{OG}=\frac k2\vec a+\frac l2\vec b, \vec{OH}=\frac 12\vec a+\frac l2\vec b.$$

Letting $I$ be the intersection point of $EG, FH$, there exist $m,n$ such that
$$\vec{EI}=m\vec{EG}, \vec{FI}=n\vec{FH}.$$

The former gives us
$$\vec{OI}-\vec{OE}=m\left(\vec{OG}-\vec{OE}\right)\iff \vec{OI}=(1-m)\vec{OE}+m\vec{OG}=\frac{1-m+mk}{2}\vec a+\frac{1-m+ml}{2}\vec b.$$

The latter gives us
$$\vec{OI}-\vec{OF}=n\left(\vec{OH}-\vec{OF}\right)\iff \vec{OI}=(1-n)\vec{OF}+n\vec{OH}=\frac{k-kn+n}{2}\vec a+\frac{1-n+nl}{2}\vec b.$$

Now since $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are linearly independent, the following has to be satisfied :

$$\frac{1-m+mk}{2}=\frac{k-kn+n}{2}\ \text{and} \frac{1-m+ml}{2}=\frac{1-n+nl}{2}.$$
These give us $m=n=1/2$ since $(k,l)\not=(-1,-1).$
Hence, we get
$$\vec{OI}=\frac{k+1}{4}\vec a+\frac{l+1}{4}\vec b.$$

On the other hand, letting $P,Q$ be the midpoints of $AC, BD$, we have
$$\vec{OP}=\frac{k+1}{2}\vec a, \vec{OQ}=\frac{l+1}{2}\vec b.$$

Finally, we obtain
$$\vec{PI}=\frac 12\vec{PQ}.$$
Since this represents that $I$ is on the line $PQ$, we now know that we get what we want. **Q.E.D.**

**P.S.** If $(k,l)=(-1,-1)$, then $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, which is an easy case.

Comment: So, $\vec{OC}$ is just the scaled version of $\vec{OA}$? That doesn't make sense. I mean, the two clearly have a different direction, don' they?

Comment: In my answer, $O$ is the intersection point of $AC, BD$.

Comment: Oh, you should mention that. I thought $O$ referred to the origin.

Comment: I think so. sorry. I added.

Comment: How did you get $\vec{OI}=\frac{k+1}{4}\vec a+\frac{l+1}{4}\vec b$? Forgive me, but I'm new to vector geometry.

Comment: @Gerard: I added some explanation.

Comment: Do you have anything that is unclear to you?

Answer (score 1):

Using the same diagram as above in the question, I will go with this way:

FHKI is a parallelogram [HK || CD by applying equal intercepts theorem in the triangle ACD. Similarly FI || CD; and IK || AB, FH || AB. Since opposite pairs of sides are parallel, FHKI is indeed a parallelogram ]

Similarly EIGH is parallelogram.

Now the key argument:

Let the diagonals HI and EG of parallelogram EHGI meet at point J. Then J bisects HI.

Similarly, let the diagonals HI and FK of parallelogram FHKI meet at point J'. Then J' bisects HI.

But there can be only one midpoint of a line [which is HI in current situation], hence J = J'.

Hence EG, FK, HI are concurrent.

Answer (score 1):

Let ABCD be the a quadrilateral with E, F, G, K as midpoints respectively of AB, BC, CD & DA. Let H, I be mid-points of diagonals AC & BD.

EFGK is a parallelogram as a pair of opposite sides are parallel to the respective diagonals fo the quadrilateral.

With the mid-points of the sides of the quadrilateral joined, they form th diagonals of the parallelogram EFGK, meeting at J ..(1)

In ΔABC,EH||BC,2EH=BC. Likewise, in ΔDBC,IG||BC,2IG=BC. Therefore, IG||EH & IG=EH.

In ΔACD, GH||AD 2GH=AD. Likewise, in triangle ΔABD, FI||AD & 2FI=AD. Therefore GH||FI & GH=FI

This renders FHGI a parallelogram with its diagonals mutual bisectors. They can be seen to meet at J ..(2)

(1) & (2) proves the required condition discussed in the question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).